# Where can I find a list of the properties of Transformer.setOutputProperty?

Tags: java, xml

I would like to know where I can find the list of properties settable by the method [`Transformer.setOutputProperty(String name, String value)`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/xml/transform/Transformer.html#setOutputProperty(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Rather obscurely, they're documented in the [Xalan proprietary javadoc](http://xml.apache.org/xalan-j/apidocs/org/apache/xalan/transformer/TransformerImpl.html#setOutputProperty%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29):

> This method is used to set or override
>   the value of the effective xsl:output
>   attribute values specified in the
>   stylesheet.
>
> The recognized standard output
>   properties are:
>
> ```
> * cdata-section-elements
> * doctype-system
> * doctype-public
> * indent
> * media-type
> * method
> * omit-xml-declaration
> * standalone
> * version
> ```
>
> For example:
>
> ```
> tran.setOutputProperty("standalone", "yes");
> ```

Answer (score 13):

Also, check out the `javax.xml.transform.OutputKeys` class.

```
tran.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.STANDALONE, "yes");
```

Answer (score 5):

Essentially, the properties can be anything you put into it. Properties are "defaulted" by default properties specified by [section 16 of the XSL Transformations (XSLT) W3C Recommendation](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#output).
If any of the argument keys are not recognized and are not name-space qualified, the property will be ignored and not returned.   If you really need a complete list - I'd say Sec 16 of the W3C recommendations is a good place to start.

Answer (score 0):

You can find the documentation of `javax.xml.transform.OutputKeys` in the Oracle docs:

For Java 10:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/javax/xml/transform/OutputKeys.html

```
CDATA_SECTION_ELEMENTS
DOCTYPE_PUBLIC
DOCTYPE_SYSTEM
ENCODING
INDENT
MEDIA_TYPE
METHOD
OMIT_XML_DECLARATION
STANDALONE
VERSION
```